# DRF formdata with file and nested array of objects not taking nested array of objects

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Unable to send nested objects when using formdata. Since I have large number of files using base64 is not a solution. current solution was to use `JSON.stringify` from client side for `product_timings` and send it as a single field, But I would like to know if normal modal field with file upload is possible with DRF. Here is my `APIView`

```
class ProductCreateApi(APIView):
    permission_classes = [permissions.DjangoModelPermissions]
    queryset = Product.objects.all().order_by("-created_at")
    parser_class = [MultiPartParser, FormParser, JSONParser, FileUploadParser]
    
    class ProductCreateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
        class ProductCreateProductTimingSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
            class Meta:
                model = ProductTiming
                fields = ['start_time', 'end_time']
        product_timings = ProductCreateProductTimingSerializer(write_only=True, many=True)
        product_images = serializers.ListField(
            child=serializers.ImageField(allow_empty_file=False, use_url=False),
            write_only=True
        )

        class Meta:
            model = Product
            fields = '__all__'
```

In post man I tired

`product_timings[0][start_time]: 09:30:00`

`product_timings[0][start_time]: 09:30:00`

Still it is throwing validation error messages like

```
{
    "product_timings": [
        {
            "start_time": [
                "This field is required."
            ],
            "end_time": [
                "This field is required."
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Please note neither base64 image field for `product_images` nor single JSON field for `product_timings` is not the solution I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1):

The format your are looking for has no dots, and no secondary `[]`:

`products[0]starttime`

Here is a helper function to do this in python3.6 or greater, but it is easy to adapt.

```
def flatten_dict_for_formdata(input_dict: dict):
    """
    Recursively flattens nested dict() for passing as form data
    > {"a": [{"b": "c"}]         => "a[0]b":    "c"
    > "i": {"j": "k"}}           => "i.j":      "k"
    > "x": {"y": {"z": [1, 2]}}  => "x.y.z[0]": 1, "x.y.z[1]": 2,
    """

    results = {}

    def flatten(value, prefix="", previous=None):
        if isinstance(value, dict):
            if previous == "dict":
                prefix += "."

            for key, value in value.items():
                flatten(value, prefix + key, previous="dict")

        elif isinstance(value, (list, tuple, set)):
            for i, value in enumerate(value):
                flatten(value, prefix + f"[{i}]")

        else:
            results[prefix] = value

    flatten(input_dict, "")
    return results
```

A longer example of the output:

```
flatten_dict_for_formdata(
    {
        "character": {
            "name": {"first": "Clark"},
            "favorite_color": ("Red", "White")
        },
        "superpower": "Super Strength",
        "appearances": [
            {
                "title": "Action Comics #1",
                "dialog": [
                    {
                        "speaker": "Clark",
                        "tokens": ["Up", "In", "The", "Sky"]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
)
```

Converts to:

```
"character.name.first": "Clark",
"character.favorite_color[0]": "Red",
"character.favorite_color[1]": "White",
"superpower": "Super Strength",
"appearances[0]title": "Action Comics #1",
"appearances[0]dialog[0]speaker": "Clark",
"appearances[0]dialog[0]tokens[0]": "Up",
"appearances[0]dialog[0]tokens[1]": "In",
"appearances[0]dialog[0]tokens[2]": "The",
"appearances[0]dialog[0]tokens[3]": "Sky"
```